# Hooking system call ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hook, system-calls

I want to try to hook the system call open, write in Ubuntu 16.04 - 64bit - kernel version: 4.15.0-45-generic

My code is below:

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <asm/pgtable_types.h>
#include <linux/highmem.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#define syscall __NR_open
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("LAMDUCANH _ CNTN");

/*MY sys_call_table address*/
//ffffffff81e001e0
void **system_call_table_addr;
/*my custom syscall that takes process name*/
asmlinkage int (*custom_syscall) (const char* path, int flag, mode_t mode);
/*hook*/
asmlinkage int hook(const char* path, int flag, mode_t mode) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Pname Syscall:HOOK! HOOK! HOOK! HOOK!...ROOOFFIIOO!");
    printk(KERN_INFO "The process that opens the file is: %s\n", current->comm);
    printk(KERN_INFO "The file name: %s\n", path);
    return custom_syscall(path, flag, mode);
}

/*Make page writeable*/
int make_rw(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    if(pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW){
        pte->pte |=_PAGE_RW;
    }
    return 0;
}
/* Make the page write protected */
int make_ro(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}
static int __init entry_point(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Module load successfully");   
    system_call_table_addr = (void*)0xffffffff81e001e0; 
    printk(KERN_INFO "Address system call open = %p", (void*) system_call_table_addr[syscall]);   
    custom_syscall = system_call_table_addr[syscall];    
    make_rw((unsigned long)system_call_table_addr);    
    system_call_table_addr[syscall] = hook;
    return 0;
}
static void __exit exit_point(void){   
    printk(KERN_INFO "Module unload successfully"); 
    system_call_table_addr[syscall] = custom_syscall;    
    make_ro((unsigned long)system_call_table_addr);
    return;
}
module_init(entry_point);
module_exit(exit_point);
```

I find my address system call table by this way:
[sudo cat /boot/System.map-4.15.0-45-generic | grep sys_call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6BRa.png)
Anh address system call table is ffffffff81e001e0

But when I insmod the kernel object, I got an error like this

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffff81e001f0
```

How can I fix this error??? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this error relates to address system call table or not, but you can try below code:

```
system_call_table_addr = (void*)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");
```

Hope this helps you.